# CrossDomainError with very libearl client access policy

Tags: wcf, cross-domain

Is it just me or shouldn't the following client access policy allow anyone to do anything?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<access-policy>
    <cross-domain-access>
        <policy>
            <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
                <domain uri="*" /> 
             </allow-from>
             <grant-to>
                 <resource include-subpaths="true" path="*" /> 
             </grant-to>
        </policy>
    </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

I just created it and placed it at http://localhost/clientaccespolicy.xml and my web service still yields an exception with the message: CrossDomainError

Is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a specific port, other than 80, to access the cross-domain resource, be sure to specify that port in the url. The protocol, domain, server and port must match exactly.

Also, validate that your policy is actually being accessed by observing the log on the server.